# I am unable to delete an empty repository in gitLab

Tags: gitlab

This is the error I get.

> This project was scheduled for deletion, but failed with the following
> message: ContainerRegistry::Path::InvalidRegistryPathError

Comment: possibly related bug issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27483

Answer (score 1):

If this is a self-hosted instance, a GitLab administrator can delete this project from the rails console.

To start the rails console, from the command line on the gitlab instance:

```
gitlab-rails c
```

Then use the console to delete the project.

```rb
user = User.find_by_username('root')
project = Project.find_by_full_path('mygroup/myproject')
::Projects::DestroyService.new(project, user, {}).execute
```

Alternatively, you may be able to fix the error that prevents the deletion. Change the namespace for the project to a valid name like 'deleteme123' then try deleting it again.

Comment: I am not hosting a gitLab instance. I am talking about repositories on gitlab.com. I am not sure if I have access to gitlab console. I tried changing the name and then deleting but no success.

Comment: @Sarthchoudhary have you tried changing the project _path_ (note this is different than the name) to not have an underscore? If the underscore appears in the group part of the name, try transferring the project to another namespace. Otherwise, you'll have to contact GitLab support.

Comment: The thing is I have underscore in my user name, and I tried changing it several times but it doesn't work either. No errors, it just doesn't work.

Comment: @Sarthchoudhary Can you transfer the project into another namespace? Like create a new group and transfer the project there.

Comment: No, it gives error 500.

Comment: Yeah, in this case it sounds like you'll have to contact support to get the project deleted or wait until the bug is fixed. @Sarthchoudhary

Comment: I understand; thanks.